# What is $\|g\|_{\text {op}}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> > Let $$\ell^2 = \left \{x = \left (x_1,x_2, \cdots \right )\ :\ x_i \in \Bbb C,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left |x_i \right |^2 < \infty \right \}$$ be a normed linear space with the norm $$\|x\|_2 = \left ( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \left |x_i \right |^2 \right )^{\frac 1 2}.$$ Let $g : \ell^2 \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ be the bounded linear functional defined by $$g(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x_n} {3^n}\ \text{for all}\ x = \left (x_1,x_2, \cdots \right ) \in \ell^2.$$
> >
> > Then find $\|g\|_{\text {op}} = \sup \left \{\left |g(x) \right |\ :\ \|x\|_2 \leq 1 \right \}.$

I am trying by taking $x \in \ell^2$ with $\|x \|_2 = 1$ like for every $n \in \Bbb N$ we can consider the sequence $x^{(n)} = \left (\frac {1} {\sqrt n}, \frac {1} {\sqrt n}, \cdots , \frac {1} {\sqrt n}, 0,0, \cdots \right ) \in \ell^2$ having $\frac {1} {\sqrt n}$ as it's first $n$ components and all other zero. Then they have the property that $\left \|x^{(n)} \right \|_2 = 1$ and for each $n \in \Bbb N$ we have $$g \left ( x^{(n)} \right ) = \frac {1} {2 \sqrt n} \left ( 1 - \frac {1} {3^n} \right ).$$ As $n$ increases the sequence $\left \{g \left ( x^{(n)} \right ) \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ decreases to $0.$ So $\sup\limits_{n \geq 1} g \left (x^{(n)} \right ) = g \left (x^{(1)} \right ) = \frac 1 3.$ So $\|g\|_{\text {op}} \geq \frac 1 3.$ Can we make this bound more precise? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a_n) \in \ell^{2}$ and $g(x_n)=\sum a_n x_n$ the $\|g\|_{op}=\|(a_n)\|_2$. To see that use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to see that $\|g\|_{op}\leq \|(a_n)\|$. Then  note that $g(\overline {a_n})=\sum |a_n|^{2}$ so $\sum |a_n|^{2} \leq \|g\|_{op} \|(a_n)\|$. This implies that $\|g\|_{op}\geq \|(a_n)\|$.

In our case we get $\|g\|_{op}=\sqrt {\sum \frac 1 9^{n}}=\frac  1{2 \sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Yeah I observed that after I posted this question here. Moreover the supremum is attained . To see  that one can take $x = \left ( \frac {2 \sqrt 2} {3} , \frac {2 \sqrt 2} {3^2} , \cdots , \frac {2 \sqrt 2} {3^n} , \cdots \right )$ then it is easy to see that $\|x\|_2 = 1$ with $g(x) = \frac {1} {2 \sqrt 2}.$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes. In  general the sup is attained at $x=(a_n) / \|(a_n)\|$ and that is exactly your $x$. @mathmaniac.

Comment: I don't think the comment you made above is correct. Let me illustrate. For instance take $x = \left (\frac 1 2 , \frac {1} {2^2}, \cdots , \frac {1} {2^n}, \cdots  \right ).$ Then it is easy verify that $\|x\|_2 = \frac {1} {\sqrt 3}.$ Take the sequence $\frac {x} {\|x\|_2} = \left (\frac {\sqrt 3} {2} , \frac {\sqrt 3} {2^2}, \cdots , \frac {\sqrt 3} {2^n}, \cdots  \right ).$ Now what is $g \left (\frac {x} {\|x\|_2} \right)$? Well $$g \left (\frac {x} {\|x||_2} \right) = \sqrt 3 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {6^i} = \frac {\sqrt 3} {5} \neq \frac {1} {2 \sqrt 2}.$$

Comment: So your argument fails in the above example. Am I doing any mistake @Kavi Rama Murthy sir?

Comment: @mathmaniac.  Please check your calculations again. Also, you are mixing up $a$ and $x$. $g(\frac x {\|x\|_2})$ is $\|x\|_2=\frac  1{\sqrt 3}$ in your new notations and that is what I have also claimed. Why should this be $\frac 1 {2\sqrt 2}$? With this new $x$ that you have defined the question has changed and it has nothing to do with $\frac 1 {2\sqrt 2}$ any more.

Comment: So what do you mean by "in general the supremum is attained at $x = (a_n)/ \|(a_n ) \|$"? What is $(a_n)$ here? Do you mean $(a_n) = \left (\frac 1 3 , \frac {1} {3^2} , \cdots , \frac {1} {3^n} , \cdots \right )$?

Comment: Where do I make mistake in my calculations? What is $g(x)$? Is it not $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {6^n} =\frac 1 5$?

Comment: When I say 'in general" am not looking at you definition of the function $g$. I am looking at $g$ defined by $g(x)=\sum a_nx_n$. In your case $a_n=\frac  1 {3^{n}}$. In general $\|g\|=\sqrt {\sum |a_n}^{2}}$ which works out to $\frac 1 {2\sqrt 2}$ in your case. So in the counter-example you trying to give to my claim what you have is $a_n=(\frac  1{2^{n}})$ but you have denoted this by $x$ and that is causing some confusion.

Comment: Well. I understand now. Thanks sir for your help. Can you recommend me some good book of functional analysis for upcoming NBHM PhD scholarship examination? I find difficulty in solving some of the questions appeared in previous year papers. Can you suggest me how do I improve at this areas? Which book should I follow to solve exercises which helps me to crack NBHM exam? I have cracked it in previous year also but I wasn't selected in the interview held in Indian Statistical Institute, Kolkata. I know that it's not relevant question but if you suggest me some references it will be appreciated.

Comment: @mathmaniac. Topology by Simmons has basic stuff in FA and it is easy to read if you are comfortable with basic point set topology. Rudin 's RCA is good reference with lost of exercises.